# Furnace not starting after i added c wire connection

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I just got a sensi lite system. My system didn't have c wire but once i connected c wire, the furnace is not even starting even if i set the temp to 90 degrees. Yesterday without. Connection i was able to set the thermostat and furnace was working but then thermostat would disconnect from wifi. Any help or suggestion will be helpful

[image]

Comment: Wifi, smart thermostats are nice till your neighbours hack into the system.  You did change the root password?  Are you so far away that standing up to change the temp is not possible?

Comment: Put it back the way it was. If it doesn't work even then, look for the fuse you may have blown while working on it.

Comment: What make and model is your furnace?

Answer (score 0):

You might just have weak WiFi signal.

Check the reception with your phone WiFi signal. If weak install WiFi extender (it is just a plug in).

Check if you get 24 Volt (AC) between the R and C on the thermostat.